# Core Plot scatter graph line gradient

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm using Core Plot to draw a scatter graph.  The points (which are in an ordered sequence) are connected by line segments.  I need to visualize the line direction (and it might overlap or cross itself).  I've been able to set each of the points to a different color form dark to light, like this:

[image] and [image]

I'd like to have the line change color, too, in a linear fashion from the first point to the last.  How can I use CPTGradient to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The gradient options for lines in Core Plot are the `lineGradient` to give the line a 3D effect or the `lineFill` (with a gradient fill) to fill the entire line path with a gradient. The `lineFill` works by using the line path as a mask to show part of a rectangle filled with the gradient.